# jquery datepicker code not working (set specific date as default)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to set the date to a specific one on page load so I'm trying this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() { 

  var queryDate = new Date();
queryDate.setFullYear(2009,11,01);
$('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});


$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("s.php", $("form").serializeArray(), function(message) {
                window.location="v.php" 
            });
        });
    });

</script>

//The form part where is displays the datepicker:

<form action="#" method="POST">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="date">Date:</label>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </div>     
</form>
```

The problem is that nothing's changing ... the default is still the current date :o/

Any ideas anyone please?

UPDATE: Tried this code:

```
var queryDate = new Date(2009,11,01);
$('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});
$('#date').val(queryDate);
```

And the date is appearing in the input box but the calendar is not in the right month nor date ... Moving foward but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm what if you tried this

new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

```
var queryDate = new Date();
queryDate.setFullYear(2009,11,01);
$('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});
```

Then the datepicker knows its a date object and how to handle it.

---

EDIT
Ok - all i did was copy the code exactly as you got it here several posts the same suggestion- and the code you edited. Added tags- inlcuded jquery and jquery ui..
I see no problem- the defuatl date is 2009.

```
</head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
var queryDate = new Date();
queryDate.setFullYear(2009,11,01);
$('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});

$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("s.php", $("form").serializeArray(), function(message) {
            window.location="v.php" 
        });
      });
   });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
//The form part where is displays the datepicker:

<form action="#" method="POST">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="date">Date:</label>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</div>     
</form>

</body>
```

Result (no styles sheet attached)
[image]

**Working example- tell me what is wrong**

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/nptgn/

Comment: answer updated-- i did not change any of your code.. are you sure you are not double initializations the calendar somewhere?

Comment: Looking but cannot see anything :o/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/nptgn/  next time please do this before asking question- will save confusions , aight! :D

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code it does work. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure sure the suggested answer here is not working. As I have tested it display on the right month and year, but only not highlighted the date. This could be because the date format.

Try adding this code to have a default value on your date.

```
$('#date').val(queryDate);
```

Then you may see that the format is different with the date in date-picker. If you manage to set the right format with date-picker, you get the things you wanted.

Comment: I've tried this: $('#date').val(queryDate);

 var queryDate = new Date();
queryDate.setFullYear(2009,11,01);
$('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate}); but I see no changes on the calendar :o/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var queryDate = new Date(2009,11,01);<br/>
  $('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, I solved it like this

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", defaultDate: "+3m"} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$('#mydate').val("2009-11-01");